# Immutable JS Record Structural Sharing

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I'm migrating some code to use Immutable JS, specifically a Record Type, and I'm implementing some code that converts regular JS objects that have been read from an API into the Record types, and I'm keen to ensure I'm writing this in a way to allow for as much structural sharing as possible.

Imagine `NodeRecord` has 3 fields `id, type and parent` (there are other, but thats enough for 
the example)

`id` is always unique

`type` is a set of < 10 options (Line, Rectangle, Oval ...)

So I just have 10 "seed" i.e.

`const LineSeed = new NodeRecord({type: 'line'})`

Records for all the different types, and then when converting from JS objects to Immutable, I can do something like

```
if (node.type === 'line') {
    return LineSeed({id: nodeId})`
}
```

And that means the {type: 'line'} part of the structure is reused ... Whoop!

What I was wondering next, can I do the same thing with the `parent` field, there are too many different combinations of `parent` / `type` to be able to have a full set of seed objects,

So I was wondering if there is some flavour of `merge()` that would make this work?

I've tried standard merge and it doesn't i.e.

```
node1.merge({parent: '111'}) // What could go here which would mean the
node2.merge({parent: '111'}) // parent gets shared between node1 and node2
```

As expected, I can see through the debugger that there are two different instances of `["parent", "111"]` stored under the two nodes.

Now you might think I'm getting ahead of myself, but the version of the code without immutable is already bumping up against problems with using too much memory, so don't want immutable adding to that (and hopefully using immutable will avoid some of that)

Comment: For `node1` and `node2` to have the `parent` be shared, you have to give both calls to `merge` the same immutable map as a parameter.

Comment: @4castle Nah that doesn't work either I've debugged through the immutable code and realise now that its not implemented in a way that could work ... I'll answer my own question

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into the Immutable JS code and see that this isn't possible.

The guts of it is each key/value gets stored internally as an 2 element array

i.e. `['parent', '111']`

Now in the `.merge` code it ends up effectively calling

`Map.set('parent', '111')` for any item being merged in ... which must mean the 2 element array is being created somewhere below that.

And that all sort of makes sense, the code doesn't really treat merging an Immutable object any differently than merging a regular one.